Expected value of a recursive process
The grass in my garden grows by 1cm every week. Every Sunday morning I cut the grass by selecting half of the blades independently at random and cutting them to zero length. Assuming I have been doing this for a long time what is the average length of the blades in my garden?
Since the problem is recursive one way to solve it I though was to say. If $X_i$ representes the length of the blades in the garden after the $i$-th Saturday, then we have:
$$X_{i+1} = 0.5 \times (X_i +1) + 0.5 \times (X \times 0) =  0.5 \times (X_i +1)$$
So assuming the expectation converges after a long time by solving the equation I found $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1$.
Though I am not convinced by what I am doing... Like what does $X$ actually represents and on what is it defined?
A proper way of defining it is assuming the garden is a square and then we defined: $X:[0,1]^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}_{+}$. So for each blade in the garden $X$ gives its length.
But then we need to define a random variable that takes randomly half of the points in: $[0, 1]^2$. Hence I really don't know how to solve this problem properly because I feel like in my argument above something is completely missing.
Is there a way of solving this problem properly? And I am right by saying that the first argument above is not rigourously correct?

Your equation needs some fixing. If $X_i$ is the length of a blade at time $i$, then $X_i$ is a random variable, and your equation is wrong.
What you could write is
$$X_{i+1} = Y_i \cdot (X_i +1)$$
where $Y_i$ is random variable, independent of $X_i$, taking the values $0,1$ with equal probability.
Then $$E[X_{i+1}] = E[Y_i] E[X_i +1] = \frac{E[X_i]+1}{2}  $$
or
$$\mu_{i+1} = \frac12 (\mu _i + 1) \tag 1$$
where $\mu_i = E[X_i]$.
That is, your equation is correct not for the length but for the expected length.

So assuming the expectation converges after a long time by solving the equation I found $E[X]=1$

Indeed, but the assumption (that it converges to a constant) is not justified.
But from inspection we can see that $\mu_1 = \frac12 \mu_0 +\frac12$, $\mu_2 = \frac12 (\mu_1 +1)=\frac14 \mu_0 + \frac{3}{4}$, so we can guess the exact solution: $$\mu_i = \frac{1}{2^i}\mu_0 + \frac{2^i-1}{2^i}= 1 +
 \frac{\mu_0-1}{2^i}$$
which we can check by complete induction.
From this, we conclude $\mu_i \to 1$ regardless of the initial value.
